# sass media query unexpected behavior for min-width

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries

I am using media queries to change the font size of some text on my site. However it is not working as I understand them to work.

```
p {
font-size: 3rem;
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
max-width: 1600px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;}
```

Currently the min-width: 768px applies to everything under 992px. For example at 440px width it still has a font size of 2rem. The 3rem font size is never used. One interesting thing to note is that this is only happening in Chromes Responsive device tester. If I make the actual window small then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you include in your `<head>` this meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the page at the width of its own screen. So if that screen is 320px wide, the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default, in lieu of a responsive meta tag).

Source: [Css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my issue. I haven't seen that meta tag before. Is that a common thing for most sites?

Comment: It is common thing when making responsive page layouts. With this the browser window size is as wide as screen. It's in [bootstrap basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going mobile first (using `min-width`) you are supposed to apply lowest size first.
Try with:

```
p {
font-size: 1.5rem;
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
max-width: 1600px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;}
```

Comment: Oh you are right! I was thinking of it a little backwards thanks.